# RelativeLayout Interchild Margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hello I am aware that using `RelativeLayout`, we can place a view next o the other using `layout_toRightOf`, `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_above`.

However, I am wondering how do we add some spacing/ margin to it? If I simply set the margin, it will cause the view to set the margin against the parent view. any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,the margin will work to the view's neighbors,not parents,for example if you set `layout_marginLeft=20dp` to view1,then the left of  view1,assuming view2,will have 20dp margin with view1,not with parents at all.

Comment: thanks, the reason why it does not work in my case is because I am setting all programmatically using the addRule method. Guess it doesn't work when I don't have an accompanying XML file.

Comment: @JayVDiyk,  yes,when facing cases like this need to program in java,I usually write xml layout to prove it can work then translate the layout to java code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe adding **Padding** settings to your RelativeLayout might work.

So there are basically two ways you can set the spacing for your view. **Padding** and **Margins**.

Consider the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output** :
[image: Output of the above code]

1. **Padding** : Padding settings describe the area **inside the view** 
   where the view is allowed to draw its content.

For example: changing the padding settings in the above code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Text 1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output** : 
[image: Output after adding padding of 20dp]

*(Did you notice that now, the content is drawn after a distance of 20dp from the boundaries of the view)*

2. **Margin** : On the other hand, Margin settings describe the area where the view itself can be drawn.

Adding margin settings (and removing the padding) to the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Text 1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**:
[image: Output after adding margin to the views]

As you can see, the view this time, is drawn after leaving a distance of 20dp around it.

So the two spacing techniques, padding and margin, first one works on the "content of the view" and the later one on "the view itself".

Answer (score 1):

Use padding to set margin inside a view:
    `android:padding="5dp"`
     `android:paddingLeft="5dp"`
      `android:paddingRight="5dp"`
      `android:paddingBottom="5dp"`
       `android:paddingTop="5dp"`